# How to get the string representation of a nested class

Tags: swift, reflection, typeof, mirror

In my reflection library [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) I have the following problem when class definitions are nested (class within a class). Below is a worked out case which can be found as a unit test [here](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/blob/Swift3/EVReflection/EVReflectionTests/EVReflectionIssue114b.swift#L70) and The location in the library itself where the code needs to change is [Here](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/blob/Swift3/EVReflection/pod/EVReflection.swift#L591)

> I need to get the Internal Swift string representation of a nested
>   class for a property which is an array of that nested class.

Below you can see a unit test where I am able to get the correct type for the property company that is an other object. It will output `_TtCC22EVReflection_iOS_Tests13TestIssue114b10Company114` instead of `Company114`

When I try the same for the friends property my goal is that it outputs something like: `Swift.Array<_TtCC22EVReflection_iOS_Tests13TestIssue114b7User114>`
What do I have to do to get that?

As you can see in the test I have various assignments to the value valueType. None of these assignments work. I am only able to get an `Array<User114>` or an `Swift._EmptyArrayStorage`.

As you also can see in the test is that if I set a breakpoint and do a po in the output window I am able to get the correct output. So what code will accomplish the same in my code?

```
class TestIssue114b: XCTestCase {
    class User114: EVObject {
        var company: Company114 = Company114()
        var friends: [User114] = []
    }

    class Company114: EVObject {
        var name: String = ""
        var address: String?
    }

    func testIssueNestedObjects() {
        let x = User114()
        print("type 1 = \(NSStringFromClass(type(of: x.company)))") // output = type 2 = _TtCC22EVReflection_iOS_Tests13TestIssue114b10Company114
        print("type 2 = \(testIssueNestedObjects(x.friends))")

    }

    func testIssueNestedObjects(_ theValue: Any) -> String {
        var valueType = ""
        let mi = Mirror(reflecting: theValue)
        valueType = NSStringFromClass(type(of: (theValue as! [NSObject]).getTypeInstance() as NSObject))  //  NSObject
        valueType = "\(type(of: theValue))"   // Array<User114>
        valueType = "\(mi.subjectType)"      // Array<User114>
        valueType = ObjectIdentifier(mi.subjectType).debugDescription //"ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000118b4a0d8)"
        valueType = (theValue as AnyObject).debugDescription      // <Swift._EmptyArrayStorage 0x10d860b50>
        valueType = NSStringFromClass(type(of: theValue as AnyObject)) // Swift._EmptyArrayStorage
        // set breakpont en enter this in output window: (lldb) po type(of: theValue)
        // Ouput will be: Swift.Array<EVReflection_iOS_Tests.TestIssue114b.User114>
        return valueType
    }
}
```

**Background info:**
Actually the end goal is that I have to be able to create instances of the object that I can add to the array. Since the array property is only available as a result from a Mirror command the variable will be of type Any. I do have an extension for arrays in place that will return a new array element. however I am only able to get that when the Any is casted to `Array<NSObject>` and because of that my extension will return an NSObject. So I would like to get a string like `Swift.Array<_TtCC22EVReflection_iOS_Tests13TestIssue114b7User114>` I can then get the parts between <> and then create an instance for that using NSClassFromString.

Comment: `String(reflecting: type(of: theValue))`

Comment: @Jiri Wow! that works! Could you change the reply into an answer? Then I can give you the 250 bounty points!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String(reflecting: type(of: theValue))`

**update by Edwin Vermeer:**
For the required conversion to the internal string representation i now have the following function (still in draft)

```
public class func convertToInternalSwiftRepresentation(type: String) -> String {
    if type.components(separatedBy: "<").count > 1 {
        // Remove the Array or Set prefix
        let prefix = type.components(separatedBy: "<") [0] + "<"
        var subtype = type.substring(from: prefix.endIndex)
        subtype = subtype.substring(to: subtype.characters.index(before: subtype.endIndex))
        return prefix + convertToInternalSwiftRepresentation(type: subtype) + ">"
    }

    if type.contains(".") {
        var parts = type.components(separatedBy: ".")
        if parts.count == 2 {
            return parts[1]
        }
        let c = String(repeating:"C", count: parts.count - 1)
        var rv = "_Tt\(c)\(parts[0].characters.count)\(parts[0])"
        parts.remove(at: 0)
        for part in parts {
            rv = "\(rv)\(part.characters.count)\(part)"
        }
        return rv
    }
    return type
}
```

Comment: Since it's returning EVReflection_iOS_Tests.TestIssue114b.User114 I still have to cast it to _TtCC22EVReflection_iOS_Tests13TestIssue114b7User114 but that is a strait forward conversion. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Sorry about that, I was only trying to achieve the correct output from `testIssueNestedObjects(_:)` specified in the last comment in that method.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, you have helped a lot! This is good enough for me.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem in the EVReflection library. I even did some refactoring so that I now always use the String(reflecting: type(of:value))